# Helper Data not found in magento2

Tags: magento2, page-builder

i try to install this extension :

https://www.magesolution.com/front-end-cms-page-builder.html

i do all steps, and when go to my site i see error 500.

the message of error :

```
[24-Jun-2019 08:04:59 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Class 'MGS\Core\Helper\Data' not found in /home/pt1byfxrpoja/public_html/app/code/MGS/Fbuilder/Helper/Data.php on line 15
```

I go to file Data.php and i see this 15:

```
class Data extends \MGS\Core\Helper\Data
```

Its true, but see error ,,, where is problem ?

Comment: Search in your *Helper* I mean in your `Data.php` maybe you r using some other class with the same name of *Data* in your `di`

Comment: and also upload your `Data.php`(Helper) class here

Comment: Your class`\MGS\Core\Helper\Data` exists in the file but there is no such a file `Data.php` exist in your path `\MGS\Core\Helper\Data` see in your directory `Data.php is existed under `\MGS\Core\Helper\Data` path?

Comment: If the file exists the check namespace & class name of that file.

Comment: the file `Data.ph` found and no any duplicate class

Comment: @KhalidAlmallahi your issue is resolved right? http://www.drama-spares.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your class`\MGS\Core\Helper\Data` exists in the file but there is no such a file `Data.php` exist in your path `\MGS\Core\Helper\Data` see in your directory `Data.php is existed under` \MGS\Core\Helper\Data` path?

**Solution:**

You got this error because you have not installed the `MGS_Core` extension. and your extension `MGS_Fbuilder` class extends `class Data extends \MGS\Core\Helper\Data` so that class not found.

So basically your extension `MGS_Fbuilder` dependent on `MGS_Core` extension. just install  `MGS_Core` extension. your error will be solved.

---

**Update:**

Maybe there is default extension issue I found the solution for that [Check this link](https://community.magento.com/t5/Magento-2-x-Technical-Issues/MGS-Frontend-Builder-Issue/m-p/103850#M6270)

I hope it helps!

Comment: i try install php bin/magento module:enable MGS_Core but see thiss error http://prntscr.com/o5vaag

its not in your steps here ?
!http://themes.magesolution.com/fbuilder/installation

Comment: First, you need to install `MGS_Core` extension then you have to enable the extension.

Comment: ok,, How can install it ?

Comment: See my updated answer i have shared one link

Comment: This is default extension issue see this link https://community.magento.com/t5/Magento-2-x-Technical-Issues/MGS-Frontend-Builder-Issue/m-p/103850#M6270

Comment: i dont see the command to install MGS_Core

Comment: the Mpanel not found in public_html/app/code/MGS

Comment: From where you got extension `MGS_Fbuilder`?

Comment: from here https://github.com/arrowhitech-gp/magento2-cms-builder

Comment: Just install this extension https://github.com/arrowhitech-gp/core then check

Comment: i install it and my sitw down http://www.drama-spares.com

Comment: see the error log. run setup upgrade.

Comment: are you mean  php bin/magento setup:upgrade

Comment: Yes also check in error log file.

Comment: thank you 

but after Go to admin > MGS > [Page Builder] Page Builder Setting and change "Active Front-end Builder" to "Yes"
i dont see the page builder in page /

http://prntscr.com/o5w1qe

Comment: I don't know what was the issue for that. you have to debug for that.

Comment: Check setting as well as the error log file.

Comment: Have you solved issue?

Comment: yes thank you :-)

Comment: Thanks for your appreciation ;)

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this error you have not installed the **MGS_Core** module with **MGS_Fbuilder**.

To install **MGS_Core** module goto the below link:

> https://github.com/arrowhitech-gp/core

And install it and then check if everything works.

Comment: Are you getting the error after installation of Core module?